# issue with excel after saveas overwrite data

Tags: vb.net, excel

So I have written the below code that open my excel file and save it as text file

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelData.xlsx")
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

xlSheet.SaveAs("C:\Data.txt", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows)

xlBook.Close
```

The problem is after it save the file i9t prompt me do you want to save changes and when I click Yes it overwrite the file with the latest opned sheet from the excel.

How can I stop it from overwriting and stop it from prompt me for changes?

Comment: -1 this shows no research effort. This has been asked (and answered) many times already

Comment: If you like my question kindly upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following line at the start of your macro:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Then no dialog boxes will appear during its running. This will include the popup that shows when closing `xlBook`.

Comment: This is a vb.net application windows application not a macro.

Comment: When I added it it gave me the below error:

Error 13 'DisplayAlerts' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.

Comment: That should probably be `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` then.

Comment: If you like my question upvote it

Comment: You don't like my question?

Comment: @MohammadMMohammad - Please stop asking for up-votes on all your questions.

Comment: Why? what's in it with you?

Comment: There is no rule prevent me asking for up-votes.